# Sharing values between different Classes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, variables, methods

I have a WPF Project where I want to save DataRows from a DataGrid into an "options" class and retrieve those variables in another window.

Thats how I save my Variable from my DataGrid into my "options" Class (**mainWindow.xaml.cs**):

```
options.title = Convert.ToString((showEntries.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row["title"]);
```

This Variable im saving via a getter and setter (**options.cs**):

```
public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { title = value; }
        }
```

And now I want to retrieve the saved variable in another window(**updateDatabse.xaml**):

```
private void getUpdateEntries()

        {
            Options returnValues = new Options();
            titleBox.Text = returnValues.Title;
        }
```

**My Question is: Why is my textbox "titleBox" empty when running my code.**

Comment: You are confusing classes and their instances.
You are saving in one instance, but you are reading from a new, different instance.

Comment: ok so I need to remove the "Options returnValues = new Options();" part right ? but how do I share my Options.Title value with this method if its not in the same class ? dont I need some kind of parameter then ?

Im new to coding

Comment: Since you are new to coding, just go through the concept of "Static" in C#, it will help to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic of your task does not provide for the creation of several instances of classes (and as far as I understand your explanations, this is so), then you can use the Singlton implementation.
Example:

```cs
public class Options
{
    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    private Options() { }

    public static Options Instance { get; } = new Options();
}
```

```cs
Options.Instance.Title = Convert.ToString((showEntries.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row["title"]);
```

```cs
private void getUpdateEntries()
{
    titleBox.Text = Options.Instance.Title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed things up.

```
    private void getUpdateEntries()
    
            {
                Options returnValues = new Options();
                returnValues.title = Convert.ToString((showEntries.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row["title"]);
                titleBox.Text = returnValues.Title;
            }
```